# Locking configuration of a button in tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

So i would like to know if there is a function/command i could use which stops a button being reconfigured. In my program i have a list of buttons, and each time the button is clicked (events) the value inside the button increases by one. However, there are several buttons which i would not like this cycling feature to occur on - any help with how i could achieve this? I shall present my code where the buttons are generated and where i have the event function below.

```
def LeftClick(event):
    if c==True:
        next_value = " 123456789 "
        try:
            current_value = next_value[next_value.index(str(int(event.widget['text']))) + 1]
        except ValueError:
            current_value = "1"

        event.widget.config(text=current_value)

#Create a 9x9 (rows x columns) grid of buttons inside the frame
for row_index in range(9):
    for col_index in range(9):
        if (row_index in {0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8} and col_index in {3, 4, 5}) or \
                (row_index in {3, 4, 5} and col_index in {0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8}): #Colours a group of 3x3 buttons together to differentiate the board better.
            colour = 'gray85'
        else:
            colour = 'snow'
        c=True
        btn = Button(frame, width = 12, height = 6, bg=colour) #create a button inside frame 
        btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", LeftClick)
        buttons.append(btn)
        if row_index==4 and col_index==1:
            btn.config(text=2)
            c = False
```

I have attempted using c as a variable to determine which buttons can be changed and which cant, however this has been unsuccessful.

Comment: you're the one adding the binding to add this behavior. Did you try simply _not_ adding the binding for widgets that shouldn't have this behavior?

Comment: No because then it will unbind all of then. I still want the feature of most buttons, just not the latter one,

Comment: I didn't say unbind from all, just unbind from the ones you don't want. You're asking how to remove functionality that you yourself are adding. The proper solution to that problem is "dont' add it".

Comment: That makes sense! How would i do that for an indivudal button?

Comment: just use a basic `if` statement. If it's a normal button, add the binding. If not, don't.

Comment: I dont understand how i would be able to do this. The bind feauture is either bind all buttons or no buttons (at least the way i have it set up currently). Could you propose some sample code on how i could do this??

Comment: simply use `if c: btn.bind("<Button-1>", LeftClick)`

Answer (score 1):

Solution is so simply so it is even stupid to write it

```
    c = True

    btn = Button(frame, width = 12, height = 6, bg=colour) 
    btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)

    if row_index==4 and col_index==1:
        btn.config(text=2)
        c = False                   

    if c:
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", LeftClick)

    buttons.append(btn)
```

or maybe even without `c`

```
    btn = Button(frame, width = 12, height = 6, bg=colour) 
    btn.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)

    if row_index==4 and col_index==1:
        btn.config(text=2)
    else:
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", LeftClick)

    buttons.append(btn)
```

---

BTW: Button has `command=` which you could use instead of `bind('<Button-1>')`

BTW: `c` is global variable which changes value inside `for` loop so it has the same value for all buttons inside `LeftClick`.